# Transform raster data to data.frame

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have multiple rasters and the idea is to create a column for each layer inside a data frame, but I'd like to use `mydf$layername` or `mydf[[layername]]` operations in a loop. In my example:

```
library(raster)
```

Create an empty data frame:

```
mydf<-NULL
```

3 layers simulation:

```
## Create a simulated RBG rasters
r <- raster(nc=30, nr=30)
r <- setValues(r, round(runif(ncell(r))* 255))
g <- raster(nc=30, nr=30)
g <- setValues(r, round(runif(ncell(r))* 255))
b <- raster(nc=30, nr=30)
b <- setValues(r, round(runif(ncell(r))* 255))
rgb<-stack(r,g,b)
```

Population of data frame(`mydf`) with each layer information and use `"names"` as a variable name

```
for (i in 1:length(rgb@layers)){
mydf$assign(paste0(rgb[[i]]@layers)) <- as(as.im(rgb[[i]]), "SpatialGridDataFrame")$v
}
Error in mydf$assign(paste0(rgb[[i]]@data@names)) <- as(as.im(rgb[[i]]),  :
```

or

```
for (i in 1:length(rgb@layers)){
     mydf[[assign(paste0(rgb[[i]]@layers))]] <- as(as.im(rgb[[i]]), "SpatialGridDataFrame")$v
}
Error in paste0(rgb[[i]]@layers) :
```

There is any solution for this `mydf$assign(paste0(rgb[[i]]@layers))` or `mydf[[assign(paste0(rgb[[i]]@layers))]]` operations?

Comment: What are the packages used?

Comment: Why are you using `assign()` here? Just use `mydf[[rgb[[i]]@data@names]]` (the `paste0()` isn't doing anything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going about this very much the wrong way. You should not use `@`. For example, instead of `rgb@layers` use `nlayers(rgb)`. Also, you should *never* use `assign`.

Example data

```
library(raster)
rgb <- brick(nc=10, nr=10, nl=3)
set.seed(1)
rgb <- setValues(rgb, round(runif(3 * ncell(r)) * 255))
names(rgb) <- c("R", "G", "B")
```

You do not need that loop at all. You can just do

```
v <- as.data.frame(rgb)
head(v)
    R   G   B
1  68 167  68
2  95  90  56
3 146  69 132
4 232 253  69
5  51 162  46
6 229  54 132
```

Or

```
v <- data.frame(values(rgb))
```

You *could* that with a loop. The easiest way would be to use a list

```
x <- list()
for (i in 1:nlayers(rgb)){
     x[[i]] <- values(rgb[[i]])
}

df <- data.frame(x)
colnames(df) <- names(rgb)
```